# SQL: Get tupels of records with same many to many relationship

Tags: sql

I got another SQL-Challenge.

I have the following relations (I removed all unimportant attributes):

passenger(**id**)

flight(**id**)

passenger_flight (**passenger_id**,**flight_id**)

Now I want to get tupels of all flight_id's having exactly the same passenger list.

Hope you can help me.

John

Comment: I'd call it tables and columns, to speak SQL. What have you tried?

Comment: It could be DB specific. E.g. for MySQL you can use GROUP_CONCAT with ordering by ID. SO you group by flight calculating kind of "sum" of ids (concat all IDs ordered) in a subquery. Then JOIN the subquery to itself ON sub1.passengersConcat=sub2.passengersConcat and sub1.flight_id!=sub2.flight_id. Distinct flights ids from mthe query is your  answer